# Xamarin Forms: Is it possible to view the pictures by right or left flip?

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe

I have a photo gallery in my application. If I select a photo, the selected photo is shown on another page with right and left arrows. When tapping the left arrow the previous picture of the album is visible on the screen and if taps the right arrow the next picture in the album will come on the screen.

**Screenshot**

[image]

I need to view the next/previous pictures without arrow tapping. Is it possible to view the pictures by right or left swiping? Is there any controls for recognizing the right/left screen swiping?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CarouselView is here for you !!

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-0-feature-preview-an-entirely-new-point-of-collectionview/

[image]

> Technical note: Enable the CollectionView (which also enables the
>   CarouselView) with a feature flag just before you initialize
>   Xamarin.Forms in your MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

If you don't want to use the new feature you can add SwipeGestureRecognizer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe

For fast image loading and caching i use this library

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 0):

Careful though because `CarouselView` is in preview, you shouldn't use it in production app.

So till `CollectionView` is not released you can use this one:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#carousel-layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I need to view the next/previous pictures without arrow tapping. Is it possible to view the pictures by right or left swiping? Is there any controls for recognizing the right/left screen swiping?

If you want to do this, I suggest you can use CarouselViewControl. You need to install **CarouseView.FormsPlugin** by nuget. You can tap arrow or right or right swipping to view picture

then add this reference

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="Demo1.listviewcontrol.Page3"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <cv:CarouselViewControl
            x:Name="carousel"
            AnimateTransition="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            PositionSelected="Handle_PositionSelected"
            PositionSelectedCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"
            Scrolled="Handle_Scrolled"
            ShowArrows="true"
            ShowIndicators="true" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public Page3 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    private void Handle_PositionSelected(object sender, CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.PositionSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Position " + e.NewValue + " selected.");
    }

    private void Handle_Scrolled(object sender, CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Scrolled to " + e.NewValue + " percent.");
        Debug.WriteLine("Direction = " + e.Direction);
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<View> _myItemsSource;
    public ObservableCollection<View> MyItemsSource
    {
        set
        {
            _myItemsSource = value;               
        }
        get
        {
            return _myItemsSource;
        }
    }

    public Command MyCommand { protected set; get; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<View>()
        {
            new CachedImage() { Source = "a1.jpg", DownsampleToViewSize = true, Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill },
            new CachedImage() { Source = "c2.jpg", DownsampleToViewSize = true, Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill },
            new CachedImage() { Source = "c3.jpg", DownsampleToViewSize = true, Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill }
        };

        MyCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Position selected.");
        });
    }

}
```

I use CacheImage, so installing Xamarin.FFimageLoading.Forms by nuget.

Please add the following code in Mainactivity OnCreate method

```
 CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
        CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
```

[image]